# How can I send email from localhost using swiftmailer?

Tags: email, localhost, swiftmailer

How can I send email from localhost using Swiftmailer? also, how can I configure mail catcher with Swiftmailer. Mailcatcher is working with PHP mail() function but not with swiftmailer, I am using vagrant.

```
require_once ('/include/SwiftMailer/vendor/autoload.php');

$transport = new Swift_SendmailTransport('localhost', 25);
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
    ->setFrom(['xxxxxxxxx' => 'xxxx'])
    ->setTo(['xxxxxxxxxx' => 'xxxx'])
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, if you can provide us with the code you have tried so far we can help you further.

Comment: Basically, I want to use swift mailer library but the sending mail should work like internal php mail() function (without smtp for instance). we have a mail server installed that handles email coming from php mail(). and for local testing, I am using mail catcher.